# openpyxl ValueError formatting new rows of data

Tags: python-3.x, openpyxl, valueerror

The following code works great the first time I run it (when it creates a new spreadsheet).
When I try to run it again (update existing sheet) to add more data (additional rows) I get the following error

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/PythonPrograms/Workout Program/test_excel_format.py", line 35, in 
cell.style = wdata

File "C:\Users\Mark\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\styles\named_styles.py", line 193, in append
raise ValueError("""Style {0} exists already""".format(style.name))
ValueError: Style wdata exists already

```
   from openpyxl import Workbook
   from openpyxl.styles import PatternFill
   from openpyxl import load_workbook
   from openpyxl.styles import Font, Color, Alignment, Border, Side, colors
   from openpyxl.styles import NamedStyle
   from datetime import date
   from os import path

   filename = "format_wb_test.xlsx"

   if path.exists(filename):
      workbook = load_workbook(filename)
   else:   
      workbook = Workbook()    

   sheet = workbook.active

   tdate = date.today()

   data = [tdate, "Data 1", "Data 2", "Data 3"]

   wdata = NamedStyle(name="wdata")
   wdata.font = Font(bold=True)
   wdata.alignment = Alignment(horizontal="center", vertical="center")

   for x in range(1, 3):
       sheet.append(data) # appends the data to the first empty row.
       print("current row: ", sheet._current_row)
       ucell = "A" + str(sheet._current_row)
    
       wdata_row = sheet[sheet._current_row]
       for cell in wdata_row:
              cell.style = wdata

       sheet[ucell] = tdate

   workbook.save(filename=filename)
```

I want to be able to add new rows of formatted data esch time I run this code.

Comment: Styles registered automatically on their first use and can then be referenced by name. It probably makes sense to register the style outside the loop and the set it for the cells by name: `cell.style = "wdata"`

Comment: Hi Charlie, I'm still a bit confused. I did define wdata outside the loop. When I try to set cells to the style in the loop I get the error. I guess I'm not understanding exactly what you are saying.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any way to use a NamedStyle to update the format for rows added to an existing
workbook/sheet. If you define the NamedStyle you get the "Already Exists" error. If you don't then you get an error that the "NamedStyle is not defined". The doc states pretty much verbatim what Charlie Clark said in his comment above, "Styles registered automatically on their first use and can then be referenced by name."  It does not elaborate or show examples of how to use an existing NamedStyle. Given this I gave up trying to use a NamedStyle and updated the code as follows to make it work. If there is a way to do this with NamedStyle I'd love to see it.

Here's the updated code.

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.styles import PatternFill
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.styles import Font, Color, Alignment, Border, Side, colors
from openpyxl.styles import NamedStyle
from datetime import date
from os import path

filename = "format_wb_test.xlsx"

if path.exists(filename):
   workbook = load_workbook(filename)
else:   
   workbook = Workbook()    

sheet = workbook.active

tdate = date.today()

data = [tdate, "Data 1", "Data 2", "Data 3"]

#   wdata = NamedStyle(name="wdata")
#   wdata.font = Font(bold=True)
#   wdata.alignment = Alignment(horizontal="center", vertical="center")

for x in range(1, 3):
    sheet.append(data) # appends the data to the first empty row.
    print("current row: ", sheet._current_row)
    ucell = "A" + str(sheet._current_row)   
    wdata_row = sheet[sheet._current_row]
    for cell in wdata_row:
        #cell.style = wdata
        sheet[str(cell.coordinate)].font = Font(bold=True)
        sheet[str(cell.coordinate)].alignment = Alignment              \
                (horizontal="center", vertical="center")
    sheet[ucell] = tdate

workbook.save(filename=filename)
```